# How should I design a multiscreen feature?

Tags: meteor

I work on a webapp with a workspace, where the user can create, load, and edit documents. This workspace is built with several areas, each taking care of a part of the job. A set of document loaded in a workspace is called a "project" and is stored in a "project" collection.

The data involved in a project is of two types:

1. *the set of documents attached to the project*. It is stored in the mongo document in the "project" collection
2. *the current document a specific user is working on*. I do not store it yet, I just use a set of global reactive variables to load a document and the attached informations when a user click on it. It means every time a user access to the workspace/project, he will not find the previously loaded documents but no documents loaded at all.

I now want to store the second type of data with one major requirement: to allow the user to work in an "extended mode" where one of the panels is in a dedicated browser window (supposedly on another screen). It means that if he clicks on a document in a window, the document is loaded in the other window/screen.

As far as I know, I can't send information directly from one browser window to another. I have to use the server to relay the information. So the user clicks on a document > the new loaded document id is sent to the server > the other window update accordingly.

Is my assumption correct? (the server must relay the info)

To implement this feature, I figured out a couple of solutions:

1. I attach a "project" field to the user profile mongo document. In each of these fields, I will have the last items loaded for each project and I will use this field to update one screen from the other.
2. I create a specific field in each project document where, for each user who worked on the project, I store the currently loaded document and its settings.

The first option suppose to load every project information along with the user profile (i.e. in every page) and could lead to send many times useless informations.

The second option will trigger the meteor reactivity mechanisms each time a user loads an item (without actually modifying the project) for every user connected to the project.

Each option has serious downsides, and I would like to know which one seems to be the better to you and if you can think of other alternatives.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Try to focus on one issue at once instead of polling for solutions to your use-case and asking us to judge which option is best. For example, [focus on the X](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) : Exchanging data between windows.

Answer (score 1):

You ought to be able to use one of the [reactive local storage packages](https://atmospherejs.com/packages/local%20storage) for Meteor especially if you are not concerned about not supporting non-HTML5 browsers... Can't give a massive amount of guidance on what one having not used most of them but the HTML5 local storage is usable across tabs and seems like a good place to store your data without a round trip to the server whilst also allowing it to persist between tabs.

You could also roll your own implementation (may be simpler than trying to find a package to match your needs exactly) by adding a listener to the app for local storage `setitem()` and `removeItem()` events as per this [helpful guide](https://truongtx.me/2014/06/16/cross-tab-communication-using-html5-dom-storage/) from which the below code has been shamelessly copied...

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
  // Normal browsers
  window.addEventListener("storage", handler, false);
} else {
  // for IE (why make your life more difficult)
  window.attachEvent("onstorage", handler);
};

function handler(e) {
  console.log('Successfully communicate with other tab');
  console.log('Received data: ' + localStorage.getItem('data'));
  //Add in your code to display the document on the second tab
}

localStorage.setItem('data', 'hello world');
```